Erratic Behavior in xTerm Terminal While Running Long Python Script with SSH Connections
Using xTerm terminal to run a long Python script. Randomly, while the script is running, the terminal behavior becomes erratic. New lines and indents get messed up.
For example, I see
   ****************************************************************************************************
                       **********************                  Object<i>:                    ***********************
                                           ********************** Phase 1 Method Completed !11_07_2024_09_07_39_133768 ***********************
                                                               ****************************************************************************************************


   ****************************************************************************************************
                       ****************************                  Object<i>                *****************************
                                           **************************** Phase 1 Method runTime is 8.907342 [sec] *****************************
                                                               ****************************************************************************************************

Instead of

****************************************************************************************************
************************                    Object<i>:                      ************************
************************       Phase 1 Completed !11_07_2024_10_13_01_760  ************************
****************************************************************************************************


****************************************************************************************************
****************************                Object<i>:                 *****************************
****************************       Phase 1  runTime is 9.403279 [sec]  *****************************
****************************************************************************************************

Additionally, when scrolling down with the mouse, I get "BOBOBO" instead of scrolling.
I suspect that the issue often occurs around the time the script attempts to SSH into another device. What could be causing this, and how can it be resolved?

Use the "-t" (interactive) option of ssh.  This is probably a duplicate.

Is there a way to do it without changing the script itself?

If the script doesn't use an absolute path, e.g., /usr/bin/ssh, it might be possible to put a script "ssh" on your path before that, which would (using the absolute path) add a "-t" option.
